# Maintain forward slash from MySQL select in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

## DIRECT FROM DB

When I select directly from db I get the forward slash without problem.

Query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '"', '\\"') as data FROM `table`
```

Direct query result:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}
```

## FROM PHP

But when done in PHP (specifically CI), forward slash are gone.
Query string:

```
"SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '\"', '\\\"') as data FROM `table`"
```

Query from PHP result:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}
```

Question:
How do I maintain the forward slash in PHP?

---

Note: Im trying to have a group_concat with other values as json format string so I need the slashes so it doesn't break the format, sample complete output:

```
{"field_1":"Some Value","field_2":"a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two queries are not equivalent: your PHP code evaluates to

```
php > echo "SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '\"', '\\\"') as data FROM `table`";
SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '"', '\"') as data FROM `table`
```

You're only escaping a single slash; you need an extra pair:

```
"SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '\"', '\\\\\"') as data FROM `table`"
```

which results in your original query:

```
php > echo "SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '\"', '\\\\\"') as data FROM `table`";
SELECT REPLACE(`row`, '"', '\\"') as data FROM `table`
```

Comment: It's always the silly stuff that stumps us the longest :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what goal is this, but maybe you can use this bro. the same result as forwards slashes.

```
json_encode();
```

When select, just **return json_encode($value)** so that it will maintain the forward slashes.

Comment: Hi, please read edit for the main goal. thanks for pointing out.